# Especificar comando para o CMD abrir

Tags: c#, cmd

Estou fazendo um programa simples com o Visual Studio para executar alguns comandos no CMD que eu queira, atualmente o programa tem apenas uma tela simples e um botão para abrir o cmd, mas gostaria de especificar o comando que o prompt deve rodar.

Ex: Ipconfig, flushdns, etc.

Atualmente meu código está assim, usando o `System.Diagnostics`

```
namespace Comands 
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("CMD.exe");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode utilizar o mesmo comando com um parâmetro a mais:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start( @"cmd.exe", @"/k c:\app.exe" );
```

Para mais detalhes segue um link em inglês que encontrei: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2593313/how-to-execute-console-application-from-windows-form